# If $C$ is any compact and convex set in Euclidean space set then the function $f(x) = \min\{\|x − c\| : c \in C\}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) = \min\{\|\theta x + (1-\theta)y - c\| : c \in C \}$$

for $\theta\in[0,1]$. We can write $c = \theta c + (1-\theta)c$ and then

$$\begin{aligned} \min\{ |\theta x + (1 - \theta) y - c \| : c \in C \} &= \min\{ \|\theta (x-c) + (1 - \theta)(y - c) \| : c \in C \} \\ &\leq \min\{\|\theta (x-c)\| : c \in C\} \\&+ \min\{\|(1-\theta)(y - c)\| : c \in C\}\end{aligned}$$

I'm not sure if I can apply the triangle inequality under a minimum in the last line. If I can then the result would fall out but otherwise I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Use definition of convexity , not any theorem involving derivatives.  If you show some attempt I can post an answer for you.

Comment: *Hint.* Since $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ is compact, for each $\in\mathbb{R}^d$ you can find a point $c(x) \in C$ such that $$f(x)=\|x-c(x)\|.$$ Now you may try to think what you can do for $$\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=\lambda\|x-c(x)\| +(1-\lambda)\|y-c(y)\|, \qquad \lambda \in [0, 1]. $$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've made an edit showing how far I've got. If you could provide any guidance that would be great thank you.

Comment: @SangchulLee I don't quite follow how that would help me. Since you don't work with the minimum do we end up with what we need?

Comment: The question in this argument is: min of sum $\le$ sum of min.  I think this fails in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we can find a point $c_x \in C$ such that $f(x) = \|x - c_x\|$. Then for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and for any $\lambda \in [0, 1]$,

\begin{align*}
\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) 
&= \lambda \| x - c_x \| + (1-\lambda) \| y - c_y \| \\
&\geq \| (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) - (\lambda c_x + (1-\lambda) c_y)\|.
\end{align*}

Since $C$ is convex, we know that $\lambda c_x + (1-\lambda) c_y \in C$ as well, and therefore this is further bounded from below by

$$\min_{c\in C} \| (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) - c\| = f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y). $$

This proves the convexity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<t<1$ and $c_1,c_2 \in C$. Then $tx+(1-t)y-c=t(x-c_1)+(1-t)(y-c_2)-c$ where $c=tc_1+(1-t)c_2$. Note that $c \in C$. We have $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq \|tx+(1-t)y-c\|\leq t\|x-c_1\|+(1-t)\|y-c_2\|$. You get  $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ by taking infimum over all $c_1$  and $c_2$.